# how to extract dates in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of dates in the format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS. From that, I want to grab only the date in the format DD/MM/YYYY. I tried to use LEFT function and it works, but the resulted column is not able to be grouped in Pivot Table. I tried to format the cells as DATE, but it still doesn't work. I tried to format them as DMY using the Text to Column function, but it still doesn't work. What is the solution?

Comment: Try extracting the date first as mm/dd/yyyy format and for the column set the Format as DATE Custom Type 'dd/mm/yyyy' e.g. if A1 has date in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format, set B1 cell format as DATE Custom 'dd/mm/yyyy' and the use the formula in B1 like =DATEVALUE(MID(A1,4,3)&LEFT(A1,3)&MID(A1,7,4)) See if this works and gives you extracted Date as 'DATE' format rather than Text.

Comment: thanks but that solution is very tedius, isn't there a faster way? I mean why I cant set format as DATE I dont understand

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What are you trying to do overall? Your comment about the pivot table makes me think you are only giving us part of the story. This usually result in a lot of back and forth comments about why our answers or suggestions won't work. Can you give us a bigger picture of what you are trying to accomplish so we can attempt to give a complete answer? Please update your question with your response.

Comment: I just have some data as described and I want to convert the dates into date only, without the time. I converted them as described in my first post, ie with the LEFT function. Then I make a pivot table and I want to group the dates by month and year but I cannot. It either tells me they cannot be grouped or it groups them as Group 1, instead of Months and Years. That's the whole story.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `LEFT` is that its result is a text.

You can use either `VALUE(LEFT())` to make it a number again, and the resulting column would work, or `INT()` which cuts the time away.

*Formatting* will not help in any way, as it just changes the display, but not the value or content of the cell.

Comment: mmm, it works but when in Number format, it displays 425629. Can't I make it BOTH display a date AND be a date? I mean not to be a number and display as date. I want it to be a date and display as date.

Comment: @stratos: Short answer: no.  Excel stores dates as a number of days (whole and fractional days since Jan 0, 1900).  Everything else is just formatting.  Which means in most cases, you don't have to use functions; just format the date/time to show the components you want.  If you want to truncate the time, take the integer of the date (Excel will still assume a time--it will use midnight if you select a format that includes the time).  If you want to store something that looks like a date, Excel will treat it as text and won't do date/time math with it or recognize date or time components.

Comment: Once you've done INT() to it, can you then format the resulting cell as a date?